# flatter a dynamic nested objects in order

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, nested

I have a dynamic nested array, and the level of nested is dynamic every time, I need to query the id and put them in an array in order. So it's depend on the previous function, the nested data sometimes are two level, or sometimes are three level, it can go up to 10 level.
Here are two examples.
Example one

```
let data = [
    {
        "field": "age",
        "items": [
            {
                "field": "name",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 12
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 10
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 32
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "field": "name",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 29
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "field": "age",
        "items": [
            {
                "field": "name",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 31
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 15
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 39
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "field": "name",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 55
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "field": "age",
        "items": [
            {
                "field": "name",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 43
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "field": "name",
                "items": [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 41
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "id": 6
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 98
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
result: [12,10,32,29,31,15,39,55,43,41,6,98]
```

example two

```
[
    {
        "field": "age",
        "items": [
            {
                "field": "name",
                items: [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 12
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 14
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 19
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "field": "name",
                items: [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 22
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "field": "age",
        "items": [
            {
                "field": "name",
                items: [
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 24
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "field":"gender",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 25
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 27
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 29
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 21
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "height":
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 88
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
result : [12,14,19,22,24,25,27,29,21,88]
```

how to write just one function to flatten the entire array no matter how the data change with different level nested.

So I tried the below code, however it's not giving me the current answer.

```
let level = getLevel(data);
let result = [];
data.forEach(res => {
   let flatData = res.items.flat(level);
   flatData.forEach(ele => {
      result.push(ele.id);
   })
})
```

Comment: What about [Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: When you tried to accomplish this, where did you get stuck? What code did you end up with? Why didn't it work? We're not here to do the work for you, we here to help you learn to do it yourself.

Comment: "flatter" is a funny typo.  Now I want to write a function that flatters an array; e.g., `arr => console.log("my favorite arrays are those with "+arr.length+" members")`

Comment: I tied to using flat, but it's not complete working.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the array and later items as flat array and take `id` if no `item` array is available.

```js
const
    flat = array => array.flatMap(({ items, id }) => items ? flat(items) : id),
    data = [{ field: "age", items: [{ field: "name", items: [{ field: "gender", items: [{ id: 12 }] }, { field: "gender", items: [{ id: 10 }, { id: 32 }] }] }, { field: "name", items: [{ field: "gender", items: [{ id: 29 }] }] }] }, { field: "age", items: [{ field: "name", items: [{ field: "gender", items: [{ id: 31 }] }, { field: "gender", items: [{ id: 15 }, { id: 39 }] }] }, { field: "name", items: [{ field: "gender", items: [{ id: 55 }] }] }] }, { field: "age", items: [{ field: "name", items: [{ field: "gender", items: [{ id: 43 }] }] }, { field: "name", items: [{ field: "gender", items: [{ id: 41 }] }, { field: "gender", items: [{ id: 6 }, { id: 98 }] }] }] }],
    ids = flat(data);

console.log(...ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

use fllow two API

**[].flat(Infinity)**

**[].flatMap()**

Comment: `flat` works only for nested array, not for object with array with objects.